# Filling out ANOVA table using R output

Tags: anova

I am given the following R output:

Coefficients:
             $\hspace{30mm}$  Estimate Std. $\hspace{10mm}$  Error
(Intercept)  $\hspace{10mm}$   $-0.5802$      $\hspace{20mm}$   $2.8039$
X           $\hspace{25mm}$   $15.0352$     $\hspace{20mm}$   $0.4831$

Residual standard error: $8.914$

Using this, I must complete the following ANOVA table:

Source  $\hspace{10mm}$degrees of freedom    $\hspace{10mm}$Sum of Squares    $\hspace{10mm}$Mean Square   $\hspace{10mm}$

Model   $\hspace{20mm}$1$\hspace{40mm}$   76960$\hspace{20mm}$ $\hspace{20mm}$

Error   $\hspace{20mm}$43$\hspace{40mm}$  $\hspace{22mm}$

Corrected Total$\hspace{3mm}$   44

The first entry was given, the problem uses $n=45$, $\alpha = 0.05$.
I am not sure how to get the entries just using the output I am given. I think I may be able to calculate $SSE$ with $SSE = s^2 \times DFE$ = $8.914^2 * 44 \approx 3417$. However, I am not sure if this is correct. 
We know $SSR = 76960$, so if I know how to get $SSE$, I believe I can figure out the rest. How can we calculate $SSE$ with the given information?

Comment: If "DFE" means the "degrees of freedom of the error," then doesn't your table indicate that is $43,$ not $44$?

Comment: Yes, sorry that would make sense. Is the logic correct?

Comment: Consider trying out your logic on a textbook example or even on a real dataset you have analyzed in `R`.